# How to get getBoundingClientRect in Vue Composition api?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am aware that in using the options API in Vue, we can access template refs to access `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
const rect = this.$refs.image.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
```

But I am trying to access `getBoundingClientRect()` using template refs in the composition API in Vue below:

```js
const image = ref(null);
const rect = image.value.getBoundingClientRect();
```

**This does works**, but it has this annoying error:

> Object is possibly 'null'

I even tried the following, but the error still persists.

```js
const rect = image?.value.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your referenced element a type then use `onMounted` hook to display the rect :

```js
import { onMounted,ref } from 'vue'
...
const image = ref<HTMLImageElement|null>(null);
//
onMounted(()=>{
    const rect =image.value?.getBoundingClientRect()
    console.log('rect --------------- ', rect)
})
```

This also works for Nuxt 3

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qdzpxe?file=pages%2Findex.vue,app.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation?

> [Note that you can only access the ref after the component is mounted.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs)

So until the element is mounted, it will be `null`.
[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UUFuwjAQ/IrrS0GKgiJuNEQqCKntoa1opV58icJCQh3bsteAFOXvXTuFcqi42TOz45l1xx+NSQ8e+IznrrKNQeYAvSmEalqjLbKOWdgm7FhiVbOeba1u2T1N3AslVKWVQ1ZnbB5UI+WlHD+cYQsV/hIBFCp6jOosYaMxmxdRkB5K6YFkdTYc0x3gQnu1adRuKRtQuCbZaBws8smQkdLRBaE1skSgG2M5haCX5oLXmeDFE0ip2Ze2cnOXT+ps0DhTqqILjShZ35NdAILvlRdPODpqsG126d5pRavpwrTglW5NI8G+GWyooeAzFpnAlfTe8SViaD0kZ7yqofr+B9+7U8AEf7fgwB5A8AuHpaUlDPTq4xVOdL6Qrd54Seob5Bqclj5kHGQL2ibFvtLFtM/xg2nNn251QlDuXCoEDco+6gWn317eqP4Xd5pO45xQPe9/AA1Lx8o=)